# multiple '++' working in variables, and pointers

Tags: c

This is what I think the `++` operator does

1. `a++; // a+=1 after calculating this line`
2. `++a; // a+=1 before calcuating this line`

I'm trying to study pointers, and I think that I misunderstood something.

```
int a=10;
int arr[3]={0,1,2};
int *ptr;
ptr=arr;

printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",a++,a++,++a,++a);
printf("%d,%d,%d\n", ptr[0],ptr[1],ptr[2]);
printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", * ptr++, ( * ptr)++, ++ * ptr, ++( * ptr), *++ptr, * ptr);
```

I expected that the output to be:

```
12, 12, 12, 12
0,1,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

But it wasn't. It was this:

```
13,12,14,14
0,1,2
4,3,2,2,2,2
```

Why is this?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Sir Chris Lutz edited the post for me:D
sorry for my poor english!

Comment: @Rhee - Sir? When was I knighted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not supposed to do more than one increment in arguments to a function.. because the order they can be evaluated in is ambiguous. The result of such code is undefined.

Meaning: `printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",a++,a++,++a,++a);` Should be written as

```
a++; a++;
++a; ++a;
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", a, a, a, a);
```

Try and fix that first and see if the results are still confusing.

More generally, you should only have one increment between a pair of [sequence points.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

**Edit:** Chris is right, there's no point writing four increments in the middle of nowhere. To better answer your question: For a function `void f(int)` and `void g(int)`, with `int a=0`,

```
f(++a) = f(1);
f(a++) = f(0);
g(++a, ++a) = g(???); // undefined!
```

So, increment at most once in the argument to a function.

Comment: Technically, it _should_ be written as `a += 4`, but then why would we be printing it out 4 times? This code explores undefined behavior, and trying to make it not invoke undefined behavior makes it useless. It's better to say that the code invokes undefined behavior and leave it at that.

Comment: there is no "supposed to", there is no ambiguity and it is not undefined. It is a matter of evaluation being left to right and pushing into stack being right to left.

Comment: Murali, actually splicer is correct -- the order of evaluation is not defined in C compilers.  You may be using a compiler that does as you describe.  It's behavior may change as you enable optimizations, also.

Comment: @Murali - It's probably undefined, because GCC issued over 9000 warnings saying "this is probably undefined behavior" when I tried to compile it.

Comment: Murali: maybe that is how the compiler implements it, but the standard does say you're not supposed to do it.

Comment: Yes, I was under the wrong impression, I take back my comment.

Answer (score 6):

**Don't do this. The behavior is undefined.**

From the C spec (section 6.5)...

> Between the previous and next
>   sequence point an object shall have
>   its stored value modified at most once
>   by the evaluation of an expression. 
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be
>   accessed only to determine the value
>   to be stored.
>
> Except as indicated by the syntax
>   or otherwise specified later (for
>   the function-call operator () , && ,
>   || , ?: , and comma operators), the
>   order of evaluation of subexpressions
>   and the order in which side effects
>   take place are both unspecified.

In other words, if you update the value of a variable multiple times in the arguments for a function, you're not writing legal C code.

Answer (score 3):

See 3.2 in the C FAQ:

3.2:    Under my compiler, the code

```
    int i = 7;
    printf("%d\n", i++ * i++);
```

prints 49.  Regardless of the order of evaluation, shouldn't it
print 56?

A: Although the postincrement and postdecrement operators ++ and --
perform their operations after yielding the former value, the
implication of "after" is often misunderstood.  It is *not*
guaranteed that an increment or decrement is performed
immediately after giving up the previous value and before any
other part of the expression is evaluated.  It is merely
guaranteed that the update will be performed sometime before the
expression is considered "finished" (before the next "sequence
point," in ANSI C's terminology; see question 3.8).  In the
example, the compiler chose to multiply the previous value by
itself and to perform both increments later.

The behavior of code which contains multiple, ambiguous side
effects has always been undefined.  (Loosely speaking, by
"multiple, ambiguous side effects" we mean any combination of
increment, decrement, and assignment operators in a single
expression which causes the same object either to be modified
twice or modified and then inspected.  This is a rough
definition; see question 3.8 for a precise one, and question
11.33 for the meaning of "undefined.")  Don't even try to find
out how your compiler implements such things (contrary to the
ill-advised exercises in many C textbooks); as K&R wisely point
out, "if you don't know *how* they are done on various machines,
that innocence may help to protect you."

References: K&R1 Sec. 2.12 p. 50; K&R2 Sec. 2.12 p. 54; ISO
Sec. 6.3; H&S Sec. 7.12 pp. 227-9; CT&P Sec. 3.7 p. 47; PCS
    Sec. 9.5 pp. 120-1.

Comment: Aaaah! Big scary blocks of text!

Comment: true, now reading these texts for my english aptitude. believe somthing will be better

Comment: c-faq.com seems to be down and faqs.org does not let me link to individual questions.

Answer (score 2):

It's not "per line", it's "per sequence-point" which is similar to "per expression" that the result from pre- and post- increment seem to occur.

In fact, the increment always occurs immediately.  The only variation is whether the value of the term will result in the initial or afterward value.

To fully understand that C is not line-oriented, please refer to the standard and read the parts about "sequence points."

Lines which begin with '#' are pre-processor input.  The pre-processor for C is line-oriented, but, otherwise, C itself considers the line-break characters the same as any other white space such as tab or space.

Comment: As splicer has rewritten your code -- he has separated the increments with semi-colons, which delineate statements in C.